# Guava breaks maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, guava, maven-plugin

I have some difficulties with guava and maven-plugin. I want to create a maven plugin and I used

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-plugin
```

In this plugin I need to use [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and I added it to `pom`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.6-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

After I run `mvn clean install -X` and then an error is occured:

```
[DEBUG] MojoClassVisitor#visitField
[DEBUG] MojoClassVisitor#visitField
[DEBUG] found MojoAnnotatedClass:com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$EntryFactory:MojoAnnotatedClass{className='com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$EntryFactory', parentClassName='java.lang.Enum', mojo=null, execute=null, parameters=null, components=null}
[DEBUG] MojoClassVisitor#visit
[DEBUG] MojoClassVisitor#visitField
[DEBUG] found MojoAnnotatedClass:com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$EntryIterator:MojoAnnotatedClass{className='com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$EntryIterator', parentClassName='com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$HashIterator', mojo=null, execute=null, parameters=null, components=null}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.746 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-31T19:31:06+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/238M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:helpmojo (help-goal) on project java-to-json-maven-plugin: Execution help-goal of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:helpmojo failed: 52264 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:helpmojo (help-goal) on project java-to-json-maven-plugin: Execution help-goal of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:helpmojo failed: 52264
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution help-goal of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:helpmojo failed: 52264
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52264
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scanFile (DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scan (DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.scanAnnotations (JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.execute (JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.scanner.DefaultMojoScanner.populatePluginDescriptor (DefaultMojoScanner.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.AbstractGeneratorMojo.execute (AbstractGeneratorMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.HelpGeneratorMojo.execute (HelpGeneratorMojo.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Java version

```
java version "1.8.0_151" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Maven

```
Maven home: C:\maven\apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my-group</groupId>
  <artifactId>some-id</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

  <name>some-id Maven Plugin</name>

  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.6-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <goalPrefix>some-id</goalPrefix>
          <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>help-goal</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>helpmojo</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>run-its</id>
      <build>

        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
              <debug>true</debug>
              <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
              <pomIncludes>
                <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
              </pomIncludes>
              <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
              <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
              <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
              <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install</goal>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>

      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

It is pretty strange because I just added a dependency and it breaks build.
Thanks.

P.S.
Some text becuase stackoverflow can't handle console output. 
Some text becuase stackoverflow can't handle console output. 
Some text becuase stackoverflow can't handle console output. 
Some text becuase stackoverflow can't handle console output.

Comment: Based on this `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52264` I think you have a garbled pom in your local cache etc. I would suggest to simple clean the whole `$HOME/.m2/repository` and try to rebuild. Are you locally or on a build server?

Comment: I tried to clear `repository` folder and have the same

Comment: Could you please try it on your machine, simply create project via maven archetype and add the dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use a newer version of `maven-plugin-plugin`. I think your problem is related to this plugin version (3.2) is not compatible with java 8.

Comment: I tried to update all the dependencies but have the same error, it look like infinite recursion because the lines repeat
`[DEBUG] MojoClassVisitor#visitField`

Comment: I creted project from archetype and got the same error as you. Then changed `maven-plugin-plugin` version to 3.5 and it installed fine.

Comment: Ok, I changed it in wrong place, It should be changed in `plugins`, now it works, great thanks!